# Excel roundup specific numbers only

Tags: excel

I'm looking to roundup only values less than 2, but need the rounding to take place in the same cell(s) as those with un-rounded values. 
Ex. R7 shows the sum of P7+Q7. If the sum is less than 2, I want the value to be rounded up to 2; if the sum is greater than 2, the actual value must show in that cell. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried and how can we correct your formula attempts.

Answer (score 4):

`=MAX(2, P7 + Q7)` achieves what you want. Note that `MAX` will pick the largest answer, which will be 2 if the sum is smaller, or the sum otherwise.